# Partitioning a graph into two clusters

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, graph-theory

I have a complete weighted graph G(V, E). I want to partition V into two clusters such that maximum intra-cluster edge length gets minimized. What is the fastest algorithm that solves this problem? I believe this can be solved in O(n^2) time where |V|=n. One approach would be making the graph bipartite. I could not figure out the complete algorithm. Can anyone help me to figure out the complete algorithm?

Comment: Seems like a greedy algorithm should work. Sort the edges by weight. Repeatedly remove the edge with highest weight until the graph is disconnected.

Comment: What exactly are you minimising? The sum of the weights of the two heaviest edges (one in each cluster)? Or the maximum of the two? Or...

Comment: I want to minimize the maximum edge which has both end vertices in the same cluster.

Comment: That doable in O(E log E) with the first suggestion, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two-color (depth-first search, O(n) time) a maximum spanning forest (Prim's algorithm, O(n<sup>2</sup>) time). Proof of correctness left as an exercise.

For the record, for sparser graphs with only m edges, I'm pretty sure there's an O(m)-time algorithm.

Comment: In my case, the graph is always a complete graph. So, there will be always O(n^2) edges. In the frist algorithm, I am not sure I understood your solution correctly. Are you suggesting to find the MST first and then apply two color algorithm? It would be nice if you can tell a bit details.

Comment: @Rafi Yes, find the max spanning tree and color it with two colors (doesn't matter how).

Comment: Can you give me any hint for the proof of correctness? I am trying to prove it by contradiction. But, struggling to adopt the argument of MST in the prove.

Comment: @Rafi Find the maximum intra-cluster edge length in the output of this algorithm. Argue using the MST property that every partition has an intra-cluster edge at least as long.